# How can i change the dtpicker.value format to "mmmm dd, yyyy"?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

The following code looks for the data in my MS Access table and exports it to MS Excel.

The `Date_today` field contains dates with format `"mmmm dd, yyyy"` though the data type in MS Access is set to **short text**.

My problem is that this code looks for `"mm/dd/yyyy"` in my database and I need help to change it so it will look for `"mmmm dd, yyyy"`.

Thank you!

```
Dim SSql As String
Dim DateFrom As String
Dim DateTo As String

DateFrom = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
DateTo = Format(DTPicker2.Value, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")

SSql = "SELECT * INTO [Sheet1] In 
'C:\Users\MORALES.JANNELYN\Documents\Text1.xls' 'EXCEL 8.0;' FROM 
Jannelyn_Morales "
SSql = SSql & " Where Date_today Between " & DateFrom & " And " & DateTo & 
""

con1.Execute SSql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your date data in MS Access is stored as a text field as opposed to a date/time field, you will not be able to compare the text data with a date directly within your selection criteria - you will first need to convert the text data to a date value.

This can be achieved using the `DateValue` function, e.g.:

```vb
?Format(Date, "mmmm dd, yyyy")
February 09, 2019
?DateValue("February 09, 2019")
09/02/2019
```

Hence your SQL should become:

```vb
" Where DateValue(Date_today) Between " & DateFrom & " And " & DateTo
```